# Category URL won't update without command line reindex

Tags: category, magento-enterprise, indexing, command-line

Using Magento EE 1.14.0.1 with all patches installed.  If I make a change to a category URL, the change will never manifest itself on the front end.  Cron is running, all indexes are set to "Run When Scheduled".  But even if we wait an entire day, it will never update until we run the command line:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url_category
```

Am I misunderstanding how Magento EE indexes work?  I thought that would update every five minutes once the cron runs, right?  I've checked and the cron is running the function below every five minutes.  It just doesn't do anything for the category URL.

```
enterprise_index/observer::refreshIndex
```

Comment: Check the `cron_schedule` table for crons with status `running` that are older than you think they should be. You might have crons silently failing (running out of memory) that get stuck in the database.

Comment: Makes sense.  But all records in the cron_schedule table are status pending or success.